# Finding all continuous functions such that $\int_0^xf(t)dt=(f(x))^2+C $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$C$ is a constant. FTC shows that $f(x)^2+C$ must be differentiable, which means that $f(x)^2$ is differentiable. But we don't know that $f(x)$ is differentiable then, right? I had the idea that the only two solutions are $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$, but this is assuming that $f(x)$ is differentiable. I'm not sure how to show that they are the only solutions (if they even are the only solutions).

Comment: What are the hypotheses about $f$ ? $$f(x)^2\ differentiable\ \Longrightarrow f(x)\  differentiable$$ only around points where $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(x)\not=0$. Look at $1/4(x+|x|)$ which satisfies your equation.

Answer (score 2):

If the equation in the title is true, and $f$ is differentiable, we can take the derivative with respect to $x$ of both sides. $$\frac d{dx}\int_0^x f(t) dt=f(x)$$ and $$\frac d{dx}(f^2(x)+C)=2f(x)f'(x)$$ Then:$$f(x)=2f(x)f'(x)$$ This has solutions $f(x)=0$ or $f'(x)=\frac 12$. The second one you can integrate and get $f(x)=\frac x2+c$. You just need to show if any $c$ is OK, or only $c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(x)^2$. Then $g'(x)=f(x)$ and $g(x)=[g'(x)]^2$, i.e., $\sqrt{y}=|\frac{dy}{dx}|$. This differential equation can be solved by separation of variables. From $\pm dx=\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y}}$ , we get $\pm x=2\sqrt{y} + A$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary constant, and hence $g(x)=y=(\frac{\pm x-A}{2})^2$ or $g(x)=y=0$. Therefore $|f(x)|=|\frac{\pm x-A}{2}|$ or $f(x)=0$.